# Why Object.getOwnPropertyNames() gives the methods on the prototype too?

Tags: javascript

```js
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array); 
console.log(properties);
```

Why does this code list the properties of the `Array.prototype` object too? According to my understanding it should list these properties that are found directly on the `Array` object:

```
Array.length
Array.constructor
Array.prototype
Array.isArray
Array.of
Array.observe
Array.from
Array.unobserve
```

Comment: You added custom properties to Array prototype?

Comment: No. `Array.prototype` has methods for every array object(every array in the program can use them because every array inherits from `Array.prototype`). In the snippet above I only ask for the properties on the `Array` object which is a `Function` object. and has the properties I listed above. My question is why the code lists the properties on the `Array.prototype` too?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I paste your code in the console, I get `["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "isArray", "from", "of"]` as the result. What are you getting? What browser are you on?

Comment: Why do you expect `Array.constructor`, `Array.observe` and `Array.unobserve`? Those appear to be inherited.

Comment: The array I get as output contains 25 elements. Among them are the methods on the `Array.prototype` like `Array.prototype.filter()`. This is weird to me, because I expect only the properties of `Array` to be listed. I'm on Firefox.

Comment: @Bergi Aren't `Array.observe`, `Array.unobserve`, properties on `Array`? How are they inhrited? Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be on Firefox. It does implement a non-standard extension of the `Array` constructor, where [generics function are available as static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) on `Array` itself. They are own properties, with the same names as those on `Array.prototype` but different values. They are not present in other browsers and [won't be in future Firefoxes](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/non-standard-array-string-generics-have-been-deprecated/) either.

Answer (score 1):

It is functioning correctly.

> Object.getOwnPropertyNames() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the **enumerable and non-enumerable properties** found directly upon obj....

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)**

```js
var propertiesOfArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array);

console.log(propertiesOfArray);

var propertiesOfArrayPrototype = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);

console.log(propertiesOfArrayPrototype);
```

If the properties of **Array.prototype** is what you want, then don't use **Array**, use **Array.prototype**. See update. And the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391597/2813224).

### Demo

Comment: It says `found directly upon obj`. This means that the properties returned should be `on` the object, like `Array.observe` or `Array.length`. But among the properties returned by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array)` are the properties on the `Array.prototype` object. Why is this so?

Comment: @LearningMath The output from this answer doesn't include the properties of the prototype. If you do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)` you will see all of the methods.

Comment: Yes, the output contains the methods on `Array.prototype`, method like `Array.prototype.filter()`. The array that is printed contains 25 elements. That's what is weird to me.

Comment: @LearningMath Looks like browser-dependent behavior. I just tested it with firefox and you get a different output from chrome. In that case, that's just the design decision the respective teams made.

Comment: @Andrew I run the snippet in Chrome, I get different output, 6 items in the array too. So I suppose it's implementation driven behavior.

Comment: @zer00ne On Firefox, the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array)` prints the properties of the `Array.prototype` object too.

Comment: @LearningMath I see the confusion now. Well that's good to know that Mozilla and Google are on the same page 